# Get Date From SQL Server In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have a problem with show Date from database SQL Server in JavaScript.

My JavaScript:

```
$.each(data, function (i, dt) {
                    var date = new Date(dt.Date);
                    alert(date);
                });
```

I want to show '2023-02-02' but alert show /Date(1675270800000)/. What should I type in my code?

I was trying to use:

```
var date = new Date(dt.Date);
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
var year = date.getFullYear();
alert(day +"" + month + "" + year);
```

but the alert show `NaNNaNNaN`

Comment: Can you log `dt` in the loop and show what it has

Comment: What does any of this have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: @Pointy i want to show data from database in Ajax javascript , and show it to alert

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya in log my dt.Date show Date: '/Date(1675270800000)/'

Comment: Fine. Nothing, absolutely nothing about the code you have posted has anything to do with SQL Server. It's all JavaScript. The errors you're getting are almost certainly caused by `dt.Date` being an unintelligible date to JavaScript, but we have no idea where it comes from.

Comment: `/Date(1675270800000)/` looks like the default format you'd get from [ASP.NET-based web services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb299886(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#from-javascript-literals-to-json). You need to configure custom date serialization in your web service code and how you do that depends on whether it's using [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_DateFormatString.htm) or [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support).

Answer (score 1):

I primo in the console tried your code:

```
var date = new Date(1675270800000);
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
alert(day +"-" + month + "-" + year);
```

And I got "2-2-2023".

Comment: I'm already test your code, but i get 'NaN-NaN-NaN,NaN-NaN-NaN'

Comment: Maybe you insert a string into the new Date() instead of an integer? "new Date('1675270800000');" instead "new Date(1675270800000);"?

Comment: The problem is in my class. I'm replace date type to string type. Thanks for your help